# ArcGIS Server Calculate Density to work with Geoserver GSR rest layer

Tags: analysis, geoserver, arcgis-server

Anyone know how to make the ESRI ArcGIS Server Calculate Density tool work with Geoserver GSR Rest server url work?

Calculate Density Rest: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/sa-calculate-density.htm

I get this error when I post to a tool,
Error executing tool. CalculateDensity Job ID: xyxyxyx: Invalid value for parameter inputLayer - Details : Invalid JSON for GPFeatureRecordSetLayer or GPRecordSet datatype